# GitBash returning Notepad++ error on merge

Tags: notepad++, git-bash

I tried to do a merge in GitBash today, but got the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe: -c: line 0: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe "$@"'
error: There was a problem with the editor 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe'.
```

I can't figure out why it's throwing this error, and nothing's changed in Notepad++ or GitBash. Any idea on where I can search or fix this?

Comment: Did you define notepad++ as editor or mergetool for git?

Comment: I don't remember doing it explicitly, but I must have, right? I set it all up three years back now :/

Answer (score 2):

Check you `git config -l` output (with, if you have a recent enough Git, `git config --show-origin -l`).
You can check if its declaration is [similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058535/6309).

You can see there your configuration, and get the line involving Notepad++.

Check if the issue persists if you uncompress (and add to your `%PATH%`) the [latest portable Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases): [`PortableGit-2.11.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.11.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.11.1-64-bit.7z.exe)

```
set PATH=C:\git2.11.1\bin;C:\git2.11.1\usr\bin;%PATH%
git bash
# try again the merge
```