# I am finding trouble to make VSCode as my default git editor, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am new to using Git. So I was watching some tutorial where they were using Notepad as the default editor. But I want to use VSCode as my default editor. So when I was using commands like -

```
git config --global -e
git commit
```

Instead of opening my editor, it gives me information about my CPU and Memory.

[image: CPU]

What am I doing wrong?

Yet, Code.exe is in my PATH:

[image: PATH]

And here is my config:

[image: config]

Comment: You could install a recent version of git for Windows that is now setting Vscode as the default editor...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `-multiInst -nosession`, try, as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644561/6309), the `--wait` option:

```
git config --global core.editor "Code.exe -w"
```

Comment: Can you help me out a little bit more? 
Whenever I try to commit something, It says,

There was a problem with the editor 'Code.exe --wait'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Why is this happening?

Comment: @theinterpreter17 What version of Git are you using?

Comment: @theinterpreter17 Can you try with the full path for code.exe, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34058535/6309?

Comment: @theinterpreter17 see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644561/6309 (provided you are using the latest VSCode and latest Git)